# show full content in jquery mobile select box data-native-menu=“false”

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-popup

How to show full content in jquery mobile? I used `Select` box:

```
<select data-native-menu="false">

<option>Monday</option>
<option>Sunday jnnj jnkn ikni nin iuniu niun uin iun in in io nono no no n oino  on i </option>
<option>Tuesday</option>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8xusq/65/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First give your select an ID:

```
<select data-native-menu="false" id="mySelect">...
```

For data-native-menu="false", jQM creates either a popup or a dialog (depending on the length of the list and space available) to display the options.  The ID of the created popup or dialog is the select ID plus "-listbox-popup" or plus "dialog".

So you can add CSS that allows the text of the options to wrap:

```
#mySelect-listbox-popup ul li a.ui-link-inherit, #mySelect-dialog ul li a.ui-link-inherit {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8xusq/66/)**

Comment: Thanks for your reply but after selecting in the select box it's showing in the same way.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8xusq/67/  You just need the same CSS on the select button